# Sort array with smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I need to sort an array with smarty. I try to use [this code](http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=23628#23628) :

My foreach:

```
 {foreach $hooks->addblock as $addblock}
  <ul>
  {foreach $addblock|@sortby:"prio" as $value}
    {$value@key}: {$value}
  {/foreach}
  </ul>
 {/foreach}
```

The var_dump of `$hooks->addblock`:

```
array(5) {
  ["filed_1"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(7) "filed_1"
    ["title"]=>
    string(6) "filed1"
    ["field"]=>
    string(20) "This is test filed 1"
    ["size"]=>
    int(740)
    ["prio"]=>
    int(7)
  }
  ["filed_2"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(7) "filed_2"
    ["title"]=>
    string(6) "filed2"
    ["field"]=>
    string(20) "This is test filed 2"
    ["size"]=>
    int(740)
    ["prio"]=>
    int(6)
  }
```

So, I want to sort array by value `prio` (num) ascending, but it does not come out properly!
Here the result:
[image: Output smarty]

I would like the line "field_2" be first. But I not find a solution.

This is the modifier (modifier.sortby.php): http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=23628#23628
I also have a recurring error:

> [Sat Nov 24 20:04:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice: 
>   Uninitialized string offset: 0 in
>   /var/www/libs/plugins/modifier.sortby.php(33) : runtime-created
>   function on line 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> PHP Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in /var/www/libs/plugins/modifier.sortby.php(33) : runtime-created function on line 1

This provides a clue as to how the *sortby* modifier is working.

The documentation you linked to says:

> The '-' lets you sort in reverse order, and **the # lets you sort numerically rather than as a string** (you can have '-#age' as well to sort numerically in reverse order)

Your `prio` field is an integer, and although in PHP you can do many operations transparently across integers and strings, the notice indicates that *sortby* has implemented string sort by accessing each character individually. This cannot possibly work with an integer.

So, you should use the `#` modifier:

```
{foreach $addblock|@sortby:"#prio" as $value}
                            ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it. Sorting is not a task the template engine should do. It's clearly business logic and needs to go into the controller.

Comment: why template not do it? and what solution you proposed to do this?

Comment: Sort the array in pure PHP before it is handed to Smarty, for example with `uasort($addblock, function($a, $b) { return $a['prio']>$b['prio']; });`

Comment: Arguably it's purely a presentational thing. Either way it's an interesting mystery.

Comment: Notice that Smarty templates are compiled. So what's the difference between sorting the array in the controller and compiled template? There is non. Sorting just takes place a little bit later when using Smarty approach.

Comment: Sometimes you don't have access to the backend...